# Understanding CSS grid columns better - columns, using floats

Tags: css, web, less

I am using http://semantic.gs with LESS.js. I am having difficulty understanding the concepts and the documentation wasn't entirely clear for me. I admit I haven't read up as much on LESS.js but I have read through the documentation on the Semantic Grid System website.

My understanding that there are just loads of columns and each numbered column is processed (?) by less.js.

```
// This LESS rule...
article {
   .column(9);
}

// Is compiled to...
article {
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   width: 700px;
   margin: 0 10px;
}
```

This would be largely the same, except the columns would be in different positions?

How would I find which column I would use for a footer? I'm not sure if I should apply normal css to make a footer.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely there is a LESS Mixin that has been created that defines the columns. Probably looks something like this.

```
.column(@span: 1) {
        float:left;
        width: 8.33333% * @span;
}
```

The @span is the number of grid columns you want each section to span. So say it is a 12 column grid, then you probably would want the footer to span the full width of the grid:

```
footer {
        .column(12);
}
```